# Indicator variable covariances

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

> Find $\text{Var} (T)$

I see that $E[X_i] = 0.24$,

I see that $\text{Var } X_i = 0.1824$

$$\text{Cov } (X_i, X_{i+1}) = E[X_iX_{i_1}] - E[x_i]E[x_{i+1}]$$

$$= f(1, 1) - 0.24^2$$

> $f(1, 1) = P(X_i =1, X_{i+1} = 1)$

We see $f(1, 1) \implies \{\text{ON, OFF, ON, OFF}\}, \{\text{OFF, ON, OFF, ON}\}$ since $i, i +1, i + 2$ must form a pattern and $i+1, i+2, i+3$ must as well.

$$\implies f(1, 1) = 0.4^2*0.6^2 \cdot 2 = 0.1152$$

> $$\implies \text{Cov} (X_i, X_{i+1}) = 0.1152 - 0.24^2 = 0.0576$$

**Issue:** I keep getting $\text{Cov } (X_1, X_3) = 0$, but that implies they are independent. This is **not true though** because if $X_1 = 1$ then that decides what $X_2, X_3$ will equal no?

Comment: @drhab In general yes but Bernoulli and bivariate normal are the notable exception. To OP: This result is not surprising. Let $U_i$ be the indicator that the $i$-th light is on. Note that only the $3$rd light is the overlapping one between the two groups. And you can apply Bayes theorem and easily see that $U_3$ is independent of $X_1$ - telling you there is a twist or not in the first 3 lights does not provide any information of the 3rd light - the probability of "ON" is still $0.6$.

Comment: @BGM Yes, you are right. Later I realized that in the special Bernouilli case being uncorrelated coincides with being independent. So to avoid confusion I deleted my comment and was reconsidering another. You allready have explaned nicely now.